# Spark - Update the record (in parquet file) if already exists

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am writing a Spark job to read the data from json file and write it to parquet file, below is the example code:

```
    DataFrame dataFrame = new DataFrameReader(sqlContext).json(textFile);
    dataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("year", year(to_date(unix_timestamp(dataFrame.col("date"), "YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS").cast("timestamp"))));
    dataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("month", month(to_date(unix_timestamp(dataFrame.col("date"), "YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS").cast("timestamp"))));
    dataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("year", "month").parquet("<some_path>");
```

Json file consists of lots of json records and I want the record to be updated in parquet if it already exists. I have tried `Append` mode but it seems to be working on file level rather than record level (i.e. if file already exists, it writes in the end). So, running this job for the same file duplicates the records.

Is there any way we can specify dataframe row id as a unique key and ask spark to update the record if it already exists? All the save modes seem to be checking the files and not the records.

Answer (score 1):

Parquet is a file format rather than a database, in order to achieve an update by id, you will need to read the file, update the value in memory, than re-write the data to a new file (or overwrite the existing file).

You might be better served using a database if this is a use-case that will occur frequently.

Comment: so, in that case, I need to write a data frame in another file and again need to read data frame to write in overwrite mode to replace the original one. is there any best approach to update spark records.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Apache ORC file format instead, see:

https://orc.apache.org/docs/acid.html

According your use case, or HBase if you want stay in top of HDFS.

But keep in mind that HDFS is a write once file system, if this is not fitting your need, go for something else (maybe elasticsearch, mongodb).

Else, in HDFS, you must create new files every-time, you must setup an incremental process to build a "delta" file, then merge OLD + DELTA = NEW_DATA.

Comment: That's the exact thing that I am doing but I am not able to write the new data over the old data with overwrite mode. That's the main problem.

Comment: please post a new question with all details

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at apache hudi (https://hudi.apache.org/) which provides support for updates over parquet files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34161608)